# How to get the data of a clicked card flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, syncfusion-calendar

I have a flutter scheduler calendar, I have managed to populate the scheduler with the data from the db. I have made the cards on the scheduler clickable. Each card has a set of data in the database. Like the first row populates the first card, the second is populated by the second row. I want to be able to get the click on any card and get the id, and redirect to a webview to show the webpage

```
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| ID   |title   | dose                | urls       |
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
| 1001 | Texas  | 1st                 | google.com |
| 1002 | Texas  | 2nd                 |facebook.com|
| 1003 | Ohio   | 1st                 | azure.com  |
| 1004 | Ohio   | 2nd                 | med.com    |
| 1005 | Utah   | 1st                 | tell.com   |
| 1006 | Utah   | 2nd                 | burger.com |
| 1007 | Utah   | 3rd                 | whatif.com |
+------+--------+---------------------+------------+
```

this is what I have

my function to listen for calendar clicks and try to redirect to the webpage using the id

```
void onCalendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails calendarTapDetails) async{
    if (calendarTapDetails.targetElement != CalendarElement.calendarCell &&
        calendarTapDetails.targetElement != CalendarElement.appointment) {
      print("the index  is ");
          calendarTapDetails.targetElement.index;
      return;
    }

    SharedPreferences prefs = await  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userid = prefs.getString('id');
    var email = prefs.getString('email');
    var gender = prefs.getString('gender');

    // for (Schedule s in participantSchedules){
      var scheular = await db.getSchedulesById(participantSchedules[0].id);
      print(scheular);
      print("the link is " + scheular.botUrl!+'&userId=$userid'+'&email=$email'+'&gender=$gender'+'&sendData=true');

      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebViewPage(scheular.botUrl!+'&userId=$userid'+'&email=$email'+'&gender=$gender'+'&sendData=true', scheular.title!)));

    //}

    }
```

My function to populate the items on the calendar

```
 Future<void> init() async {
    participantSchedules = await db.getScheduleByparticipantId(participantid!);
    setState(() {
      appointments = getMeetingDetails();
      _events = DataSource(appointments);
    });
  }
```

How I am getting the title and some other fields not on the table above

```
List<Meeting> getMeetingDetails() {
    final List<Meeting> meetingCollection = <Meeting>[];
    eventNameCollection = <String>[];
    //display the titles here
    for (Schedule s in participantSchedules) {
      eventNameCollection.add(s.title!);
      meetingCollection.add(Meeting(
        from: DateTime.parse(s.windowStart!),
        to: DateTime.parse(s.windowEnd!),
        background: getCalendarTileColor(
            DateTime.parse(s.windowStart!),
            DateTime.parse(s.windowEnd!), null),
        isAllDay: true,
        eventName: s.title!,
        startTimeZone: '',
        endTimeZone: '',
        description: '',
      ));
    }

    return meetingCollection;
  }
```

How can I get the id on the card  and pass it to my query below, as this only picks the value with index 0 only while I want it to be dynamic. Using a for loop loops through all the items and displays all the urls at once

```
var scheular = await db.getSchedulesById(participantSchedules[0].id);
```

so that I can populate my push route with the details from the selected card alone?

```
  Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebViewPage(scheular.botUrl!+'&userId=$userid'+'&email=$email'+'&gender=$gender'+'&sendData=true', scheular.title!)));
```

The whole class

```
//ignore: must_be_immutable
class WAFollowUps extends StatefulWidget {
  const WAFollowUps(this.participantid, {Key? key}) : super(key: key);
  final String? participantid;


  @override
  WAFollowUpsState createState() => WAFollowUpsState(this.participantid);
}

List<Color> _colorCollection = <Color>[];
List<String> _colorNames = <String>[];
int _selectedColorIndex = 0;
int _selectedCardIndex = 0;
int _selectedTimeZoneIndex = 0;
List<String> _timeZoneCollection = <String>[];
DataSource _events = DataSource(<Meeting>[]);
Meeting? _selectedAppointment;
late DateTime _startDate;
late TimeOfDay _startTime;
late DateTime _endDate;
late TimeOfDay _endTime;
bool _isAllDay = false;
String _subject = '';
String _notes = '';

class WAFollowUpsState extends State<WAFollowUps> {
  List<WATransactionModel> transactionList = <WATransactionModel>[];
  List<Schedule> participantSchedules = <Schedule>[];
  //Schedule schedule;
  CemDatabase db = CemDatabase.getInstance();
  String? participantid;

  //List<Schedules> participantsid = <Schedules>[];

  WAFollowUpsState(this.participantid);

  CalendarView _calendarView = CalendarView.schedule;
  late List<String> eventNameCollection;
  late List<Meeting> appointments;

  @override
  void initState() {
    init();
    _calendarView = CalendarView.schedule;
    _selectedAppointment = null;
    _selectedCardIndex = 0;
    _selectedColorIndex = 0;
    _selectedTimeZoneIndex = 0;
    _subject = '';
    _notes = '';
    super.initState();
  }

  Future<void> init() async {
    participantSchedules = await db.getScheduleByparticipantId(participantid!);
    setState(() {
      appointments = getMeetingDetails();
      _events = DataSource(appointments);
    });
  }


  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
            child: getEventCalendar(_calendarView, _events, onCalendarTapped)));
  }

  SfCalendar getEventCalendar(CalendarView _calendarView,
      CalendarDataSource _calendarDataSource,
      CalendarTapCallback calendarTapCallback) {
    return SfCalendar(
      view: _calendarView,
      dataSource: _calendarDataSource,
      onTap: calendarTapCallback,
      initialDisplayDate: DateTime(DateTime
          .now()
          .year, DateTime
          .now()
          .month,
          DateTime
              .now()
              .day, 0, 0, 0),
      scheduleViewSettings: ScheduleViewSettings(
        hideEmptyScheduleWeek: true,
        monthHeaderSettings: MonthHeaderSettings(
          height: 0,
        ),
      ),
      // timeSlotViewSettings: TimeSlotViewSettings(
      //     minimumAppointmentDuration: const Duration(minutes: 60))
    );
  }

  void onCalendarTapped(CalendarTapDetails calendarTapDetails,  ) async{
    if (calendarTapDetails.targetElement != CalendarElement.calendarCell &&
        calendarTapDetails.targetElement != CalendarElement.appointment) {
      return;
    }
    SharedPreferences prefs = await  SharedPreferences.getInstance();
    var userid = prefs.getString('id');
    var email = prefs.getString('email');
    var gender = prefs.getString('gender');

   // for (Schedule s in participantSchedules){
      var scheular = await db.getSchedulesById(participantSchedules[11].id);
      print(scheular);
      print("the link is " + scheular.botUrl!+'&userId=$userid'+'&email=$email'+'&gender=$gender'+'&sendData=true');

      Navigator.push(context,
          MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => WebViewPage(scheular.botUrl!+'&userId=$userid'+'&email=$email'+'&gender=$gender'+'&sendData=true', scheular.title!)));

    // }

    }

  List<Meeting> getMeetingDetails() {
    final List<Meeting> meetingCollection = <Meeting>[];
    eventNameCollection = <String>[];
    //display the titles here
    for (Schedule s in participantSchedules) {
      eventNameCollection.add(s.title!);

      meetingCollection.add(Meeting(
        from: DateTime.parse(s.windowStart!),
        to: DateTime.parse(s.windowEnd!),
        background: getCalendarTileColor(
            DateTime.parse(s.windowStart!),
            DateTime.parse(s.windowEnd!), null),
        isAllDay: true,
        eventid: s.id!,
        eventName: s.title!,
        startTimeZone: '',
        endTimeZone: '',
        description: '',
      ));
    }

    return meetingCollection;
  }

  Color getCalendarTileColor(DateTime begin, DateTime end,
      DateTime? dateCompleted) {
    final DateTime today = DateTime.now();
    _colorCollection = <Color>[];
    if (today.isBefore(begin)) { // not completed but window has not begun yet
      return Color(0xFF636363);
    } else if (today.isAfter(end) &&
        dateCompleted == null) { // not completed and window expired
      return Color(0xFFFF00FF);
    } else if (today.isAfter(begin) && today.isBefore(end) &&
        dateCompleted == null) { // not completed but still within window
      return Color(0xFF3D4FB5);
    } else if (today.isAfter(end) &&
        dateCompleted!.isAfter(end)) { // completed after window ended
      return Color(0xFFE47C73);
    } else if (dateCompleted!.isAfter(begin) &&
        dateCompleted.isBefore(end)) { // completed on time
      return Color(0xFF0F8644);
    }
    return Colors.white;
  }
}

class DataSource extends CalendarDataSource {
  DataSource(List<Meeting> source) {
    appointments = source;
  }

  @override
  bool isAllDay(int index) => appointments![index].isAllDay;

  @override
  String getSubject(int index) => appointments![index].eventName;

  @override
  String getStartTimeZone(int index) => appointments![index].startTimeZone;

  @override
  String getNotes(int index) => appointments![index].description;

  @override
  String getEndTimeZone(int index) => appointments![index].endTimeZone;

  @override
  Color getColor(int index) => appointments![index].background;

  @override
  DateTime getStartTime(int index) => appointments![index].from;

  @override
  DateTime getEndTime(int index) => appointments![index].to;
}

class Meeting {
  Meeting({required this.from,
    required this.to,
    this.eventid,
    this.background = Colors.green,
    this.isAllDay = false,
    this.eventName = '',
    this.startTimeZone = '',
    this.endTimeZone = '',
    this.description = ''});

  final String eventName;
  final DateTime from;
  final DateTime to;
  final Color background;
  final bool isAllDay;
  final String startTimeZone;
  final String endTimeZone;
  final String description;
  final int? eventid;
}


class WebViewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  final String url;
  final String title;

  WebViewPage(this.url, this.title);

  @override
  WebViewPageState createState() =>
      WebViewPageState(this.url, this.title);
}

class WebViewPageState extends State<WebViewPage> {
  final String url;
  final String title;

  WebViewPageState(this.url, this.title);

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    // Enable hybrid composition.
    if (Platform.isAndroid) WebView.platform = SurfaceAndroidWebView();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SafeArea(
      child: Scaffold(
          extendBodyBehindAppBar: true,
          appBar: AppBar(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
            title: Text(
              this.title,
              style: boldTextStyle(color: Colors.black, size: 20),
            ),
            actions: <Widget>[
              TextButton(
                onPressed: () {},
                child: Text('Finish'),
              ),
            ],
            leading: Container(
              margin: EdgeInsets.all(8),
              decoration: boxDecorationWithRoundedCorners(
                backgroundColor: context.cardColor,
                borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(12),
                border: Border.all(color: Colors.grey.withOpacity(0.2)),
              ),
              child: Icon(Icons.arrow_back, color: Banking_blackColor),
            ).onTap(() {
              finish(context);
            }),
            centerTitle: true,
            elevation: 0.0,
            systemOverlayStyle: SystemUiOverlayStyle.light,
          ),
          body: Column(children: [

            Expanded(
                child: SafeArea(
                  child: WebView(
                    initialUrl: this.url,
                    javascriptMode: JavascriptMode.unrestricted,
                    debuggingEnabled: true,
                  ),
                )
            )
          ])
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: How do you create your Card widget?

Comment: Am using the function `List<Meeting> getMeetingDetails() {`

Comment: Is 'Meeting' class your card widget?

Comment: `@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        resizeToAvoidBottomInset: false,
        body: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(5, 0, 5, 5),
            child: getEventCalendar(_calendarView, _events, onCalendarTapped)));
  }` this is how am building the cards

Comment: hi @G3ntle_Man i have added the whole dart file

Answer (score 0):

Lets say you have a set of data which is related to each Item in your list

You can have a Custom Widget as your List Item widget which accepts some extra information and also has a function which is responsible for loading data, for example:

```
class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  ...

  FoodItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    ...
  });
    
  void loadData() {
    var scheular = await db.getSchedulesById(id);
    ...
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        loadData();
      },
      child: Card(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Use this widget as your list item widget, when user taps on each item, the `loadData()` function will be called and the `id` of that item will be used

Another option is to have a field on your Item widget which accepts a function, then you can pass a function to that field from outside of your Item Widget, like this:

```
class CardItem extends StatelessWidget {
  final int id;
  final String title;
  final Function loadData;
  ...

  FoodItem({
    @required this.id,
    @required this.title,
    @required this.loadData,
    ...
  });


  void _loadData() {
    loadData(id);
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return GestureDetector(
      onTap: () {
        _loadData(context);
      },
      child: Card(
        ...
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: Hi @G3ntle_Man thank you for your answer, can you show me with my code in the class added?